# rethinkDB .then on query result

Tags: node.js, bluebird, rethinkdb

I am using nodeJS with the native rethinkDB driver and have a basic select 3 column query as follows:

```
var runQuery = function() {
var items = [];
r.connect({host: 'someHost',
port:28015,
db:'test'})
.then(function(c){
r.table('ebb1')
   .pluck("col1","col2","col3")
   .run(c, function(err,cursor){

       cursor.each(function(err,result){
           if(err) throw err;
           items.push(result);
           })
        })
    }).then(console.log(items))
}
```

I tried using `cursor.toArray()` as suggested by the rethink docs but I get a null when i try to return this, i think the result is too large. When i `console.log(result)` in the `cursor.each()` function I do see the results I expect, so I believe they are being pushed onto the `items` array, but I am unsure how to properly refer to the list after it is fully populated with the result data.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing callback style and promise which makes thing harder because you have to return promise in your callback. In your code, promise fullfillment is fired before callback is finished and log the result.

So it's better to just stick to promise. Even `toArray` can return promise too.

```
var runQuery = function() {
  r.connect({
    host: 'someHost',
    port:28015,
    db:'test'
  })
  .then(function(c){
    return r.table('ebb1')
             .pluck("col1","col2","col3")
             .run(c)
  })
  .then(function(re) {
    return re.toArray()
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    //data is the array of your query result
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```